# Wrapping elements doesn't wrap them, no exception shown

Tags: jsoup

I want to wrap each `Element` of my JSouped document. These `Elements` are defined according to the presence of the word `color` in the value of the property `style`.

The document is: `<body><span style="color: rgb(37, 163, 73);">Test</span></body>`.

So I have written:

```
Document jsoup_document_caption = Jsoup.parse("<body><span style=\"color: rgb(37, 163, 73);\">Test</span></body>");
Elements elements = jsoup_document_caption.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("style", "color");
Elements jsouped_elements = elements.wrap("<div></div>");
String jsouped_caption = jsouped_elements.outerHtml();
```

Each of the three last lines, when printed, shows: `<span style="color: rgb(37, 163, 73);">Test</span>`.

Considering in particular `System.out.println(jsouped_caption)`, we can see it hasn't been wrapped. Do you know why? I have carefully read the doc but didn't find any answer: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html + https://jsoup.org/cookbook/.

---

## Edit:

It's the same if I treat `Element` by `Element`:

```
    Elements elements = jsoup_document_caption.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("style", "color");
    for(Element element : elements) {
        System.out.println("Found element:");
        System.out.println(element);
        Element jsouped_element = element.wrap("<div></div>");
        System.out.println("JSouped:");
        String jsouped_caption = jsouped_element.outerHtml();
        System.out.println(jsouped_caption);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you `wrap` an element, the wrap is outside the element itself - it becomes it's parent, so you can do this:

```
Document jsoup_document_caption = Jsoup.parse("<body><span style=\"color: rgb(37, 163, 73);\">Test</span></body>");
Elements elements = jsoup_document_caption.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("style", "color");
System.out.println(elements); //outputs your original selection -<span style="color: rgb(37, 163, 73);">Test</span>
elements.wrap("<div/></div>");
System.out.println(elements); //still the same output - elements is unchanged
Element wrapped = elements.parents().first(); //now you have the original element AND the wrap
System.out.println(wrapped);
```

The output of the last print is `<div>
 <span style="color: rgb(37, 163, 73);">Test</span>
</div>`